# Execute SoapUI project with Maven and Jenkins

Tags: soapui, maven

I am new to Maven and Jenkins. I have automated my web service project with SoapUI (the free version). I need to include my project with DEV builds for continuous integration build. I searched in Google and seeing a lot in Maven (`pom.xml`) and Jenkins integration.

Could you please provide me how to start? Really appreciate your help.

**UPDATE:**

I installed Maven and created `pom.xml` and included my SoapUI project where I am using `jxl.jar` file for Excel read and write. I included:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.12</version>
</dependency>
```

After running `pom.xml` file, I'm getting the below message:

> Script1.groovy: 51: unable to resolve class Workbook @ line 51, column 10.
>    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inPutDateFile)); ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class Workbook

Please, has any one else faced this issue?

Comment: I installed Maven and created pom.xml and included my soapui project where i am using  jxl.jar file for Excel read and write. i included as   <dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
<artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
<version>2.6.12</version>
</dependency>   after running pom.xml file getting below message Script1.groovy: 51: unable to resolve class Workbook 
 @ line 51, column 10.
  Workbook workbook   =  Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inPutDateFile));
            ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class Workbook , Please any one face this issue

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite getting started guide for maven and Jenkins, it is with selenium, but should also work with soapui java code.

http://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins you can execute the Soapui Project/suite/testcase using SOAPUI Command line execution.
which look like:

```
Windows: testrunner.bat -s"TestSuiteName" -c"TestCaseName" <project Path>
```

`Unix/Mac: testrunner.sh -s"TestSuiteName" -c"TestCaseName" 
Lets take example:

1. Your Suite Name : ABCSuite
2. Your Project Name: ABCProject
3. Your Project location on windows is: c:/abcDirectory/abcproject.xml

Then Soapui Command line statement will be:

```
testrunner.bat -s"ABCSuite" -c"ABCProject" c:/abcDirectory/abcproject.xml
```

And Jenkins support that command line execution, so i hope you do not need any Maven to integrate with Jenkins.

You can follow following link for more info:

[SOPAUI/ReadyAPI Doc Page](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/automation/cli/functional/params?_ga=1.27782588.142681184.1434169100)

[My Blog for Soapui Command Line execution](https://testarenablog.wordpress.com/2016/08/13/soapui-command-line-execution/)

Comment: thanks for your update, finally i am able to create pom.xml and executed  and need to place in Jenkins.